# How to create a div on another page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with the creation of a div on the subpage. 
I have a form on the subpage(ADD HERO) and I want to create a div on the main page by pressing the button. Saves data from the form to localStorage, I retrieve elements using querySelection, but does not create a div. This is my code :

Homepage : (Html)

```
<div class="heros"></div>
```

Subpage (Add Hero) :

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="text" name="nameHero" placeholder="name" />
<input type="text" name="img" placeholder="foto>
<input type="text" name="price" placeholder="price / h" />
<textarea placeholder="desc Hero" name="descHero"></textarea>
<button id="btn-send" onclick="getValues(this.form)" >Submit</button>
```

Script.js

```
let number = 1;
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn-send');
const heroClass = document.querySelector('.heros');

const newDiv = document.createElement('div');

function getValues(form) {

    var nameValue = form.nameHero.value;
    var imgValue = form.img.value;
    var priceValue = form.price.value;
    var descValue = form.descHero.value;

    const obj = {
        'nameHero': nameValue,
        'img': imgValue,
        'price': priceValue,
        'descHero': descValue
    };

    localStorage.setItem(nameValue, JSON.stringify(obj));

    newDiv.textContent = number;
    heroClass.appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

In div="heroes" I want add new div.

Comment: What exactly is a "sub page"?

Comment: What you have to do is -> Add script on subpage that will fetch data from the localstorage and then write code to add div in #heroes

Comment: "sub page" This is the page with the form. I have added script on subpage and didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can do the followings as your need:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');

// optional
div.className = 'some-class-name';
div.id = 'an_Id';
div.innerHTML = '<span class="inner">Hello World!</span>';
div.textContent = 'Hello world.';

heroClass.body.appendChild(div);
```